# How to prevent the Form from opening Multiple Times

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have a application in which i have several forms. In that forms, I have a System Settings form. I have to open this form from the menu as well as a shortcut created on the desktop.

I am able to open the form from 2 places individually. But the problem is, It's opening two separate instance of the same form. it means, first, i have clicked on menu to open the form.Now my Form instance is created and it is displayed on the screen. But whenever i click on my desktop icon, It's creating another instance of the same form instead of displaying  the same form. . So it means it's displaying two instances of the same form.

But i have display one form only. I have tried and googled in the net also. I didn't find any information.

Can anybody please help me to fix this issue. Any kind of suggestion will be really helpful to me.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have 2 applications running, is this correct?

Comment: The desktop icon you mention, is that a windows desktop - if so, you're creating a whole new instance of the application. And you want your application to be instanciated once or not?

Comment: sorry for the delay,  Actually My desktop shortcut is also an exe(Source), which will open a specific form  in target exe. If we are in inside the target exe,then we can use mutex or singleton to open only one instance of the form. But As request is coming from another exe i.e. Source exe ,this mutex concept is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used semaphor concept to control this. Whenever the form is opened i am writing an entry into registry. Once the form is closed i am removing this entry.

So, whenever i try to open the form, it will check the registry entry. Based on that it will open the form.

Answer (score 3):

You need a single instance. This construct is already available within the .Net framework. Just check out [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) from Hanselman.

**Note**: I know that the namespace of this class is *VisualBasic*. But that shouldn't hinder you to use it in your C# application. It's just the name of a namespace. It doesn't meant anything about its functionality. (Microsoft had it better named Foo. In that case it would be much more popular.)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me, that you need a mutex to control that only one application instance is running at a given time.

See http://iridescence.no/post/CreatingaSingleInstanceApplicationinC.aspx for further details

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement some kind of locking mechanism to allow only one instance of your program running. I guess your System Settings program could check if other instances are running on computer on program launch, if so terminate, otherwise start a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

To throw in one more link, this post seems to cover (my understanding of) what you are trying to do.

http://dotnetperls.com/single-instance-windows-form

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a modified version of the Singleton design pattern. Try having a public  static method within the class that internally calls the constructor for the form. Then as someone suggested use a counter variable to keep track of how may times that static method is called thus giving you a metric you can use to ensure only the desired number if instance are created.